# Trouble implementing Regex in Python

Tags: python, regex

I'm having trouble implementing a regex pattern in python. My expression works in on  https://regexr.com/ but I can't get it to work in python.

Here is my expression: `[abcd][(]\d+[)]|(ab)[(]\d+[)]|(abcd)[(]\d+[)]`
I want to find and return instances `a(\d+)`, `b(\d+)`, `c(\d+)`, `d(\d+)`, `ab(\d+)`, or `abcd(\d+)`

```
expressions = re.findall(r"[abcd][(]\d+[)]|(ab)[(]\d+[)]|(abcd)[(]\d+[)]",line)
print(expressions)
```

I think it might be working because when I have something in the string that should match the pattern I get `[('', '')]` as my output instead of `[]`

Any thoughts?

Comment: Edit the question to show one or more examples with assignment to "line", output and expected output.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you misused `[(]`or `[)]`.
And `\(\d+\)` part is redundant. So you can optimize it:

```py
import re

line = 'a(123) b(11) ab(35) bc(45) abcd(1234)'

expressions = re.findall(
    r'(?:[abcd]|ab|abcd)\(\d+\)',
    line)
print(expressions)
```

output:

```py
['a(123)', 'b(11)', 'ab(35)', 'c(45)', 'abcd(1234)']
```

explanation:

- `(?:...)` is non-capturing group. It is only for grouping not capturing.
- `\(` and `\)`: `\` is escape character for special characters like `(` or `)`. `\(` matches literal `(`.

Comment: Thanks! What does the ?: do?

Comment: @usr2564301 I revised my answer.

Comment: @BoseongChoi That's a great simplification!

Comment: @JadonErwin I appended short explanation :)

Comment: @BoseongChoi thanks for the help. Is there any way I could also get the starting and ending indices?

Comment: @BoseongChoi Thanks, one always learns sth new - forgot the non-capturing group `(?:...)`. Will be useful in future!

Comment: @JadonErwin `re.finditer` makes iterator for each matched objects. They contain individual index info. See https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#match-objects

Answer (score 2):

```
expressions = re.findall(r"[abcd](\d+)|(ab)(\d+)|(abcd)(\d+)",line)
print(expressions)
```

This should work.
problem was: In Python, you don't put `(` in brackets.
If you mean the parentheses in `(d+)` literally, you have to use escaped paranthese `\(` and `\)`.

Be aware, if you put paranthese around `ab` or `abcd`
they will be listed when referencing to groupings.
I would not put parantheses as long as it is not necessary.

```
expressions = re.findall(r"[abcd]\(\d+\)|ab\(\d+\)|abcd\(\d+\)",line)
print(expressions)
```

If you want to just match `a1236`, `ab12`, `abcd12342`, then use

```
expressions = re.findall(r"[abcd]\d+|ab\d+|abcd\d+",line)
print(expressions)
```

However, if you want to capture certain parts with their repetitions, put parantheses around them.

Comment: I meant any integer by d+

Comment: yeah I realized. :)